# WPF Binding to DependencyProperty of UserControl in DataTemplate is not working

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, datatemplate, dependency-properties

i have a custom userControl with DPs and have the problem that the binding to these properties only works if i use the controls outside of datatemplates.

Outside of Datatemplates works the usercontrol great.

**XAML to Test the UserControl in a DataTemplate**

```
        <GroupBox Header="DataTemplate" Padding="5">

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Dummies}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="local:Dummy">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">

                            <common:QuarterPicker SelectedFirstDay="{Binding Gueltigkeit}" Margin="5,0" />

                            <!--control the value of the item-->
                            <TextBlock Text="Gueltigkeit: "/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gueltigkeit}"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>

        </GroupBox>
```

**MainWindow codebehind and ViewModel**

```
public partial class QuarterPickerTest : UserControl
{
    public QuarterPickerTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.Dummy = new Dummy { Gueltigkeit = DateTime.Today };

        this.Dummies = new List<Dummy>
            {
                new Dummy {Gueltigkeit = DateTime.Today},
                new Dummy {Gueltigkeit = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(6)},
                new Dummy {Gueltigkeit = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6)},
            };
    }

    public Dummy Dummy { get; set; }

    public List<Dummy> Dummies { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is the code behind of my UserControl**

```
#region SelectedFirstDay

    public DateTime SelectedFirstDay
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(SelectedFirstDayProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedFirstDayProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFirstDayProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedFirstDay", typeof (DateTime), typeof (QuarterPicker),
                                      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Today, SelectedFirstDayPropertyChangedCallback) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });

    private static void SelectedFirstDayPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var quarterPicker = dependencyObject as QuarterPicker;
        var date = (DateTime)args.NewValue;
        var quarter = GetQuarter(date);

        quarterPicker.UpdateProperties(date.Year, quarter);

        if (date.Year == quarterPicker.LeftInfiniteYear && quarter == quarterPicker.LeftInfiniteQuarter)
            quarterPicker.ShowPopupButtonLeftInfinite();
    }

    #endregion
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "binding not working". I tried your code, the data goes from your ViewModel to your control. And SelectedFirstDayPropertyChangedCallback gets called. If I change the property from the control the value gets updated in the text field in the template. The only problem that I saw, is that because the value for your first item is the same as the default value for your property the property changed handler is not calld for the first item

Comment: @devilmaster binding not working mean, that the viewmodel property that i bind to the control was not updated after i change the value with the usercontrol. BUT now i have a solution, i call the Method "UpdateProperties(year, quarter);" in the constructor of the usercontrol. If i remove that call all works great. Thanks for your time you spent to solve the problem.